# Are games Haram?

Tags: game, halal-haram

Salam Un Alaikum. I love to play games but I want to know if things, such as fighting, magic and playing them is Haram. If games are not Haram what are the boundaries?

Comment: What do you mean with fighting games? Do you mean games like Tekken on the Playstation or PSP VITA?

Comment: What do you mean with magic games? If you mean in-game creatures that use magic, I don't see what'd be wrong about that.

Comment: I speak of games like Skyrim, The Witcher III, Super Mario Odyssey and such.

Answer (score 1):

Salamu haleykum achi/achawatie

It depends on the type of game you're playing.

Let's say you're playing Monopoly. Then there is nothing wrong in doing so I'd think. Because you're not simulating a real life situation with riba. As far as I know the loans you could get in Monopoly follow the rules of islam too. So you're safe there.

Another type of game which is very popular amongst young men is betting money on something, may it be in sports games like soccer matches, horse races, etc. Then according to the Quran, you are committing a sin.

**Surat Al-Baqarah, ayat 219**

- They ask you about intoxicants and games of chance. Say: In both of them there is a great sin and means of profit for men, and their sin is greater than their profit. And they ask you as to what they should spend. Say: What you can spare. Thus does Allah make clear to you the communications, that you may ponder *

Another type of game is video games. I'd say you can play them as long as you're not getting addicted to it then you'll waste your time which is something that Allah doesn't like and you shouldn't also imitate (or at least try to avoid it as hard as you can)situations in the game in real life (e.g games with a lot of violence like Tekken). 
I'd recommend 2 hours at most a day and you should make an agreement with parents or other family members so that they can watch out over you whether or not you followed your agreement.

Puzzles like the Rubik's cube and other spacial constructions are allowed because you're enhancing your problem solving skills which will help you further  with logical reasoning.

I'll end with a note: Make sure that the things you play don't cause harm to yourself or anyone else in the long run otherwise have fun.

Comment: Monopoly is related to dice. Do you still think that it is halal?

Comment: @Shromi MONOPOLY? HALAL/HARAM? SERIOUSLY? It's just monopoly! it's a children's board game! oh man i've seen so many questions like this on this stackexchange. i even saw a question about fortnite halal/haram. man. (to clarify this is a comment supporting you, not being against you. i can't believe user24306 or any rational human being would consider monopoly or dice chess something to consider as halal/haram. of course every religion has fundamentalists, sooo....)